# style cell based on cell value in dojo gridx

Tags: dojo.gridx

I am using the dojo gridx component, and I want to format each cell based on the cell's value, I can do the styling for each cell by writing the formatter function for each column when defining the layout structure, but is it possible to write a generic formatter function that can be used for all columns

```
gridStructure: [
{
 "field": "americaGeoValue",
 "name": "Americas", 
 formatter: infoFormatter
},
{
 "field": "emeaGeoValue",
 "name": "EMEA",
 formatter: infoFormatter
},
{
 "field": "apGeoValue",
 "name": "AP",
 formatter: infoFormatter
}
]
```

this is how I am setting the data for the grid

```
storedata<portlet:namespace/>.push(
                                {
                                    "siteLabel": site.siteLabel,
                                    "siteCode": site.siteCode,
                                    "americaGeoValue": site.americaGeoValue,
                                    "emeaGeoValue": site.emeaGeoValue,
                                    "apGeoValue": site.apGeoValue
                                }
                            );
```

formatter function:

```
function infoFormatter(data) {
 console.log('formatter item'+JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

this the log

```
{"siteLabel":"test","siteCode":"test","americaGeoValue":"1","emeaGeoValue":"2","apGeoValue":"8"}
```

So, how do i write a generic formatter to check the value (americaGeoValue/emeaGeoValue/apGeoValue) and do something based on the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to style the cell based on value, instead of 'formatter', try 'class' or 'style' which are functions accepting cell as parameter like,

```
{
    "field": "emeaGeoValue",
    "name": "EMEA",
    "class": function(cell){
         if(cell.rawData()=='ABC'){
             return 'customClsForCell';
         }
     }
   }
```